# Exibir child do Firebase no Ionic

Tags: banco-de-dados, ionic, firebase, typescript, angular

Olá!

Estou com um projeto no Ionic que preciso exibir algumas promoções, no entanto preciso "atualiza-las" depois do app lançado.
Para isto estou usando o Firebase!

Eu consegui exibir no app o que eu preciso, porem preciso filtar os child.

Esse é o Data Service   .ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFire, FirebaseObjectObservable, AngularFireAuth, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable()
export class Databaseservice {

  constructor(private _af: AngularFire) {
  }

  public listProdutos(): FirebaseListObservable<any[]>{
    return this._af.database.list('/produtos/produto1');
  }
}
```

Este é o Script da pagina que sera exibido os produtos   .ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Databaseservice } from "../../providers/databaseservice";
import { FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  produtos:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public db: Databaseservice) {
    this.produtos = this.db.listProdutos();
  }

}
```

Esta é a pagina

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Teste
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <h2 class="text" *ngFor="let item of produtos | async">
    {{item.$value}}
  </h2>

</ion-content>
```

Esta é a arvore no Firebase
[image: Arvore no FIrebase]

E este é o resultado no app
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para exibir o child "nome" em uma tag 
Exemplo: {{nome.$value}}

e exibir o  child "preco" em outra tag
Exemplo: {preco.$value}}

Para que eu possa Manipular a localização na pagina ( html ) a serem exibidas.
Desde já Obrigado!

=

Answer (score 1):

onde tem {{item.$value}}
troca por 
{{item.nome}}
ou
{{item.preco}}

nesse caso depois do ponto vem o nome do campo do firebase.